# Remove duplicated rows in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have a huge text file with the following structure:

```
001 002 3
001 003 4
002 001 3
002 005 2
...
```

First and second column designate ID of the entity and the last column designate frequency of the pair. In the example above the pair with entities `001` and `002` occurs twice:

```
001 002 3
002 001 3
```

**My question:** What is the most appropriate (and efficient) way to remove duplicate rows? What programming structure should I use?

Comment: Do you need to preserve the order of the remaining entries?

Comment: `std::map<std::pair<int, int>, int>` is an other option (and you have to sort pair index, as in the provided answer).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I would approach the problem:

- On input, sort the first two strings so that `001 002` and `002 001` result in the same string.
- Store all these modified strings in a container suitable for unique elements, like `std::set` or `std::unordered_set`. You have a duplicate if the `insert` operation fails.

You can of course parse the input string further before processing and treat them as numbers. But that decision can only be made if more information about how the data will be used is available.

Answer (score 3):

An `unordered_map` hashing the numbers into something that makes order not matter, I suppose.

1. Read both ids
2. Sort them
3. Combine them into a hashed key

The value of the map is your third column, of course.

If you need to retain the original order (I think you don't), then using a regular map and combining the ids without hashing is still an option.